# Requirements Analysis Communication

Tags: documentation

How can I convert this requirement into one requirement:
For columns where there are just numbers, numeric sorting will be used. For columns that have numbers and letters, alpha-numeric sorting will be used. For Date columns, time sorting will be used. All sorting will have ascending and descending properties.

Comment: Replace period between sentences with AND?

Comment: That would be a poor requirment. What about numbers that are appropriately stored as string data (say phone numbers) do you really want to convert them to a numeric so you can order them?  Why would you sort dates by time only? Do you want 01/01/2013 22:00 to come after 06/03/2013 08:00?

Comment: What do you mean by converting many requirements into just one requirement? If you have the requirements stated above, they can probably be phrased shorter, but what else?

Comment: It seems like he has a requirement for a classic grid presentation where the users have the option of sorting on the column of their choice.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I convert this requirement into one requirement

You can't - not if you want to write good requirements.

e.g. of what you should be striving for.....

Req A. Sorting will be done based on selected column with the choice of ascending or descending sort order.

Req B. The sort sequence will be based on the data type of the column, and will support Date, Time, Number and Alpha Numeric Formats

Req B1. Date sorting will be ......

Req B2. Time sorting will be ......

Req B3. Alpha sorting will be ......

......

this might be a bit OTT - on purpose to make a point....

Answer (score 0):

"Sort the chosen column using the the appropriate collating sequence for the data type, at least numbers, date, time and alphanumeric string types should be supported both ascending and descending."

Answer (score 0):

The order that records are presented shall be determined by a composite sorting strategy.

- A sorting strategy shall consist of a comparison method for a general data format and an arrangement (ascending or descending).  Examples of general data formats include alphanumeric, numeric, and datetime.
- A composite sorting strategy is an ordered mapping of sorting strategies to column or field references where subsequent strategies act as tie breaker resolvers.